# Unable to add multiple String arrays into array using apache commons ArrayUtils

Tags: java

I'm trying to add multiple String arrays into a single array using apache commons `ArrayUtils` as below but it's saying unable to convert `Serializable` array to `String` array

```
// assigning strings arrays
String str1[] = {"hello"};
String str2[] = {"test1"};
String str3[] = {"test2"};
String str4[] = {"hello"};
String str5[] = {"test4"};
String str6[] = {"hello"};

//joining string arrays     
String[] allArrays = ArrayUtils.addAll(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5,str6);
```

Comment: `addAll` doesn't take variable number of arrays. It takes two arrays.

Comment: Its taking but expecting data type as Serializable array instead of String array

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate multiple Arrays containing multiple values you can do it in one line using Java 8 streams.

```
String[] s1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String[] s2 = new String[]{"d", "e", "f"};
String[] s3 = new String[]{"g", "h", "i"};

//one liner:
String[] result = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);
```

This technique was taken from [mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-join-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayUtils.addAll` in two ways:

```
    String[] arr1 = {"Hello", "Bye"};
    String[] arr2 = {"Good", "Bad"};

    String[] usage1 = ArrayUtils.addAll(arr1, arr2);
    String[] usage2 = ArrayUtils.addAll(arr1, "New item", "Another item");
```

The first parameter is an array. The second parameter can be either an array or single items to append to first array.

Answer (score 0):

[ArrayUtils.addAll(Object[] array1,
                              Object[] array2)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) takes only two arguments and returns new array contains all of the element of array1 followed by all of the elements array2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayUtils.addAll() iteratively, but this causes a performance impact since each time a new copy of the array is created.

```
String[] allArrays = ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.addAll(str1, str2), ArrayUtils.addAll(str3, str4)), ArrayUtils.addAll(str5,str6));
```